# How to add several programs under one folder to the Start Menu

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I've recently installed Microsoft Office 2016. When I open the Start Menu, all of the programs (Word, PowerPoint, Excel, etc.) are scattered.  I'd like to move them all into one folder.

I managed to create a folder, but dragging it is not an option. This image will give you an idea what I am wanting to do:

[image: This image will give you an idea what I am wanting to do]

Comment: You should be able to drag them into a sub-group.  Are you the administrator?

Comment: yes, personal pc, only one user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been there, done that!
By the looks of your screen shot I'd bet your using Windows 7.

Right click on one of the folders in your start menu. And you'll open a folder in this directory:

- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

There is also another directory:

- C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
  Menu\Programs

There is also another direcory:

- C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
  Menu\Programs

There are several directories where these shortcuts live. You don't have to find where each one lives, that's not important. **Just right click on the folder and select "open" and the directory will open**. To move these shortcuts just cut and paste them where you want them.

**Those six programs** on the top (your image) are shortcuts pinned to your start menu. Once you have a folder created in the open directory of your choice, just cut and paste those 6 shortcuts in that folder (not in the start menu, in the folder that you opened).

**NOTE:** I used to move my shortcuts and sort them and organize them just how you are doing. But every time you do an update on any one of those programs, you'll get another folder and more shortcuts in the original place that you don't like. It's a bummer, but that's what will become of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the start menu in Explorer and rearrange the links. Note, that you can choose your own start menu or "All Users", when you right-click on the Windows Start button.

for detailed info see [How to open the Start Menu folder in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6463/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-open-the-start-menu-folder-in-windows-7/)